# How to prevent several elements from stretching div to unwanted width when simulating mobile browser?

Tags: css

**Goal:**
My website looks OK in a wide viewport. But when I simulate a mobile view, things are not as they should be.
One or more(?) elements on the 2nd half of my page stretch their container to an unwanted width, resulting in whitespace on the right of my container elements. I want the width (and contents) of the container to adjust to the viewport, just like the upper container is already doing.

Link: [www.hermanvulkers.com](https://www.hermanvulkers.com)

**Suspected problem:**
I suspect one of the elements I circled below overflows the viewport, causing the container to stretch and other elements to go with it? I have tried to resolve it, but had no luck.

**Desired outcome:**
I aim for no whitespace on the right of the content and a page that responds to a mobile viewport as it should.

Is anyone perhaps able to figure out where the problem originates from?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please know that this is not actually the way you are supposed to ask here, see [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/1427878)

Comment: The email input field in your newsletter section has `width:300px` set, and the parent container is a flex element with direction row and without wrapping, forcing the Subscribe button (which is about 115px wide itself) to be displayed next to it ... 300px plus 115px plus additional container padding of 50px on each side, that all summed up, doesn't really fit into 375px screen width too good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be fixed using `media queries`. I noticed you were using a lot of fixed widths of certain elements with `px's` which is a big **no-no** when trying to make a responsive design. You also had some margins on certain elements that were also throwing stuff off. For media queries or a responsive design in general, I would recommend using either `%'s` `vw / vh` or other dynamic units that change with the screen.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 850px) {
  .flex-header a {
    margin-right: 1rem;
  }
  
  .container {
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
  }
  
 input[type="email"] {
    width: 100%;
  } 

  a.post {
  margin-right: 0;
 }
}
```

Give these media queries a go and change stuff around as needed.